# Using two bluetooth earphones

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I'm trying to use two different bluetooth headphones in order to talk on discord while still being able to listen to music. One headphone is used for the ears, the other for the microphone.

I'm aware I can't do this with one since it changes to Hands-Free AG Audio as soon as the microphone is activated. My problem is, when I join a call the audio keeps cutting out in the pair im using as headphones but as soon as I leave the voice channel the audio is clear.

Is there anyway to fix this?

---

The input and output devices I have on Discord:

[image: The input and output devices I have on Discord]

I use these SoundBuds Curve as my microphone. I put the cable around my ear in a position where the microphone is next to my mouth.

[image: SoundBuds Curve]

EDIT 2:

The screenshots below show that I have the Soundbuds Curve set as the default communications device and the Sony WF-1000XM3 set as my default device. By doing this I assumed I would be able to hear through my Sony headphones while talking through the microphone of my Soundbuds Curve.

[image: Windows Playback] [image: Windows Recording]

Comment: This question is really confusing. Are you actually using 2 different pairs of headphones at once?

Comment: Yes, I am using two different pairs of headphones at the same time

Comment: so how does this work? You are wearing one side of each headphone on each ear or you have 4 ears?

Comment: No, when I say headphones I mean in-ear headphones. I wear one pair and have the other just for the microphone.

Comment: can yo please update your question to include a snapshot of your input and output audio devices? Also it might be helpful to explain how you use the headphones at a microphone too.

Comment: Sorry about that, have added on the information you've asked for.

Comment: what are the input and output settings of windows ?

Comment: Have provided screenshots of my windows audio input/output settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Windows does not support playback on two separate Bluetooth devices simultaneously. While I understand that you do not wish to actually play the output on both devices simultaneously, my suspicion is that the problem arises from the same lack of support for multi Bluetooth audio.

In a [Microsoft thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/playing-sound-through-multiple-bluetooth-headsets/927bc8ce-0b83-4324-bfab-0cb1d9914360?auth=1) I read that installing a program called [Voicemeeter](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/) will allow the use of multiple Bluetooth devices simultaneously for output. Whether that resolves the issue of using one device for playback while using the other for microphone is unknown.

In [another Microsoft thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/connecting-2-bluetooth-headphones/cb646d46-545a-4ece-a006-4255ba9d7496) the user was told that they will need a Bluetooth Transmitter and splitter to be able to connect two Bluetooth headphones simultaneously.

There are also [other hardware devices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01EHSX28M) that claim to allow the use of 2 devices simultaneously, but again, I am not sure this is the solution to your problem.

Comment: In that case, I'll consider buying a Bluetooth Transmitter. Thank you for answering my question!